# firebase tutorial-modifier private is not allowed here

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, private, modifier

I'm attempting to add login functionality to my android app using Firebase. I'm following the instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth, but when I attempt to use the private modifier, Android Studio tells me it's "not allowed here." But if I don't use that modifier, I can't call mAuth in onStart.

Here is my code:

```
package com.priceelectric.xriley.priceprefab;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(user != null){
                    Log.d("loginTag", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                }
                else{
                    Log.d("loginTag", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }

            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basic Java rule. You cannot use `private`, `public`, `protected` keywords inside methods. You can only set the visibility of a "global" variable as you did for `private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;`.

**Solution:** Put `private FirebaseAuth mAuth;` right below `private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;`.

Answer (score 0):

As Ugurcan mentioned, Java does not allow modifiers like private, public, or protected on variables within methods. They can only be given such modifiers inside the class body. What you need to do is move your mAuth variable into the class (outside of onCreate). More than likely, you'll want to both declare and instantiate it all at once, rather than instantiating it later.